# Is it possible to bake lightmaps with high-poly projection in blender?

Tags: texturing, lighting

[image]

I want to bake high polygon lightmaps into low polygon uv channels. This function can be done by using render to texture in 3d max, but even if you look for it in Blender, there are only a lot of projection mapping and it doesn't seem to be visible in this regard. I tried using the Bake-selected to active function, but the map only came out dark, so I'm asking this question.

Comment: You can do it with selective-to-active bake.  It's just, do you want to bake final color?  That's what you're baking.  And do you have a material for your high poly?  For your high, plug lightmap into emission, and bake emission.  The resultant image is your high-to-low lightmap.

Comment: Does that mean baking a light map in high polygon and then baking the result in low polygon? If correct, it would be better to do 3d max as the process increases. What I wanted was to apply high polygon's detailed light to low polygon without baking the high polygon's light map.

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it would be a two-step process, bake lightmap to high poly then bake lightmap from high to low.

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. I connected a white diffuse to the high polygon and did the same, and the desired result came out. Thank you for your help. :)